# How to create a list and create variables that populate the list as the result of multiple resolved promises?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I'm creating and assigning values to a few variables at once, as the result of corresponding asynchronous functions resolving as such:

```
const [first, second] = await Promise.all([asynFunc(),asynFunc()])
```

Then, I'm creating an array with first and second:

```
const res = [first, second]
```

Is there a way to combine the steps to both create `res` as well as create and assign `first` and `second`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const res =  [first, second] = await Promise.all([asynFunc(),asynFunc()])
```

Comment: That does create *global* variables `first` and `second` and will not work in strict mode

Answer (score 0):

You can get array at the first step

```
const res = await Promise.all([asynFunc(),asynFunc()])
```

Comment: I want to create the array and create the variables `first` and `second`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for

```
const res = await Promise.all([asynFunc(),asynFunc()]),
      [first, second] = res;
```